# Получение данных с iframe (permission denied err)

Tags: jquery, nginx, javascript, iframe, cross-origin

На сервере разрешил и cors, и в nginx конфиге написал:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://domain.local";
```

а в js консоли все равно получаю в ответ:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

Для получения контента ифрейма использую:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#iframe').load(function() {
        var content = $("#iframe").contents()
    })
})
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто чем может.

Comment: @pucen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Для разрешения кросс доменных запросов к серверам мы выставляем два заголовка при ответе

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
```

Comment: Я тоже, но получить контент фрейма это не помогает.